# Use meteor oauth for custom twitter requests

Tags: twitter, oauth, meteor

I'd like to grab some twitter posts and show them in the client. I'd like to authenticate  with a user on startup of the application and when a visitor request a site a method is called that requests the tweets from the API and sends them back. Always with the same user used on startup. The user does not need to be persisted somewhere so I think I don't need the accounts packages.

Now I thought to reuse other existing packages of meteor. But there are too many and I don't know which to choose. There is twitter, oauth, oauth1, oauth2, serviceconfiguration ...

Can anybody give me a start, how to create an oauth-object to create API requests to twitter with existing built-in meteor packages? If that isn't working I will fallback to a custom implementation or a npm package. But reusing meteor packages should be best practise.

I tried to solve this problem by reading the source code of the packages but as a stranger this is a bit difficult because all the packages depend somehow on each other.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js Twitter API client, Twit, was kindly repackaged for use in Meteor. Package page here https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/twit and git repo here https://github.com/subhog/meteor-twit.